# Not able to connect Cassandra after some time [Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 10000 milliseconds]

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using a Cassandra Cluster which has three instances on AWS. And more than 100 microservice access the Cassandra simultaneously and each microservices has it's own keyspace and connection. After some point, none of these services can't access the Cassandra and throws an exception

```
Do we need to enable Pooling option for Cassandra connectivity?

Is there any issue option to get rid off this issue while creating a Cluster in java code.

What is the maximum number of connection can be used?
```

After I restart all the microservice it starts to work fine. But it started to occur after some time.
 - We have checked the Heap Usage and GC seems to be normal. 
 - nodetool status shows all three nodes are UN and no issues.
 - We tried to connect Cassandra through the console (./cqlsh) which also not working until we restart the services.

Cassandra version - apache-cassandra-3.11.2

```
We are using below jars for Cassandra drive for connection.

-cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar</br>
-cassandra-driver-extras-3.6.0.jar</br>
-cassandra-driver-mapping-3.6.0.jar</br>

if (cluster == null || cluster.isClosed()) {                    
    Builder builder = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPointsWithPorts(inetSocketAddress)
    .withClusterName(clusterName)
    .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(10000L));                    
    cluster = builder.build();
    cluster.getConfiguration().getSocketOptions()
    .setReadTimeoutMillis(readTimeoutMillis);
    cluster.getConfiguration().getSocketOptions()
    .setConnectTimeoutMillis(connectionTimeoutMillis);
```

}

```
c.d.d.c.ControlConnection Test Cluster-reconnection-1 [ERROR] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 10000 milliseconds
c.d.d.c.ControlConnection Test Cluster-reconnection-0 [ERROR] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 10000 milliseconds

2019-05-14 20:53:27.877 c.d.d.c.ControlConnection Test Cluster-worker-63522 [ERROR] [Control connection] Unexpected error while refreshing schema
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/localhost:9042] Operation timed out
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:476) ~[guava-19.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:455) ~[guava-19.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.get(SchemaParser.java:672) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.access$500(SchemaParser.java:41) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser$V3SchemaParser.fetchSystemRows(SchemaParser.java:925) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.refresh(SchemaParser.java:87) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.refreshSchema(ControlConnection.java:408) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.refreshSchema(ControlConnection.java:354) [cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager$SchemaRefreshRequestDeliveryCallback$1.runMayThrow(Cluster.java:2867) [cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ExceptionCatchingRunnable.run(ExceptionCatchingRunnable.java:32) [cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108) [guava-19.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41) [guava-19.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77) [guava-19.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138) [netty-all-4.0.53.Final.jar:4.0.53.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/localhost:9042] Operation timed out
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onTimeout(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:257) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ResponseHandler$1.run(Connection.java:1575) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:663) ~[netty-all-4.0.53.Final.jar:4.0.53.Final]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:738) ~[netty-all-4.0.53.Final.jar:4.0.53.Final]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:466) ~[netty-all-4.0.53.Final.jar:4.0.53.Final]
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: most probably you're overloaded your nodes, and they stopped with something like, OutOfMemoryException... Check the `system.log` on the nodes

Comment: also, 100 keyspaces will usually result in hundreds of tables, that is also not much recommended for Cassandra

Comment: I don't find any 'OutOfMemoryException' in the system log and the same worked fine without any issue before update the driver( Cassandra java driver 3.6.0 ). So I suspect the issue might be due to the latest driver.

Comment: Did you figure out what was the reason? I have the same issue.

Comment: I have just changed my cluster size from 3 node to 5 node and updated below properties in cassandra.yaml which fixed my issues.                   read_request_timeout_in_ms: 50000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 100000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 50000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 10000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 600000
request_timeout_in_ms: 100000